# COuld not identify the .png file in rest

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using the `Python-requests` module to make rest call from server .

Based on a rest GET I am trying to get a PNG image from the server .

To handle that I am using `Python-imaging` library

**Here is my code**:

```
RESTC_URL = 'http://10.10.10.76:8100/UCSRestService/product/' +getpid + '/callimage'
getclass = Agent()
print "+++++++++++++++++++++=--------------------------------"
getr = getclass.GETT('cdn',RESTC_URL,'apikey','SecretString')
from PIL import Image
from StringIO import StringIO
i = Image.open(StringIO(getr.content))
print i
```

But it shows

```
cannot identify image file
```

Please tell me what could be the reason for the error.

Comment: What does `Agent` create and what is `getr`? I see nothing to suggest you are using python-requests in the example. On top of that, have you tried using `BytesIO` instead? That might be more along the lines of what PIL is expecting.

Comment: Also, if `getr` is the Response object returned by requests, you should make sure the request was successful, e.g., `getr.status_code == 200` or something along those lines.